# Error on test class

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, class

My trigger is :

```
trigger TaskTrigger on Task (after insert) {
    List<Order> ordersToUpdate = new List<Order>();

    for(Task t : Trigger.new) {
        if(t.WhatId.getSObjectType() == Order.sObjectType 
            && t.Subject.startsWith('Email:')) {
                ordersToUpdate.add(new Order(Id = t.WhatId, Status = 'Sent'));
        }
    }

    update ordersToUpdate;
}
```

my test class is :

```
@isTest(seeAllData = true)
public class Test3{
    public static testmethod void TaskTrigger_Test1()
    {
        Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test');
        insert a;

        //get standard pricebook
        Pricebook2  standardPb = [select id, name, isActive from Pricebook2 where IsStandard = true limit 1];

        Product2 prd1 = new Product2 (Name='Test Product Entry 1',Description='Test Product Entry 1',productCode = 'ABC', isActive = true);
        insert prd1;

        PricebookEntry standardPrice = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id = standardPB.Id, Product2Id = prd1.Id, UnitPrice = 1, IsActive = true, UseStandardPrice = false);
        insert standardPrice;

        PricebookEntry pe=new PricebookEntry(UnitPrice = 1,Product2Id=prd1.id,Pricebook2Id=standardPB.id,isActive=true, UseStandardPrice = false);
        insert pe;

        Order o = new Order(name='Test1',AccountId=a.id,EffectiveDate=system.today(),status='draft');
        insert o;

        OrderItem oi = new OrderItem(OrderId=o.id,Quantity=decimal.valueof('1'),PricebookEntryId=pe.id);
        insert oi;

        Task t = new Task(whatid=o.id,Priority = 'normal',status='open',subject='Email:xxxx');
        insert t;

        system.assertequals('Sent',o.status);
    }
}
```

And the error is : System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, This price definition already exists in this price book: []

Any Ideas why?

Update 1. 9/3/2015

Hi after using the comments below for completing the class I have reproduce the class

```
@istest
public class Test8{
    public static testmethod void TaskTrigger_Test1()
    {
            Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test');
            insert a;     

            Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();                         

            Product2 prd1 = new Product2 (Name='Test Product Entry 1',Description='Test Product Entry 1', isActive = true);
            insert prd1;

            PricebookEntry pe=new PricebookEntry(UnitPrice = 1,Product2Id=prd1.id,Pricebook2Id=Test.getStandardPriceBookId(),isActive=true, UseStandardPrice = true);
            insert pe;

            Order o = new Order(name='Test1',AccountId=a.id,EffectiveDate=system.today(),status='draft');
            insert o;

            OrderItem oi = new OrderItem(OrderId=o.id,Quantity=decimal.valueof('1'),PricebookEntryId=pe.id);
            insert oi;


        Task t = new Task(whatid=o.id,Priority = 'normal',status='open',subject='Email:xxxx');
        insert t;

        system.assertequals('Sent',o.status);
    }
    }
```

Now the error is : System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: []

I cannot figure out the problem!

Comment: Because you have seeAllData set to true and you insert a PricebookEntry in your test class

Comment: But when I exclude the seeAllData I get that List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Comment: You need to insert a record in the Pricebook2 object before selecting or just insert a record in the Pricebook2 object and use that in the rest of the test.

Comment: Cause I am really new to coding can you please be more specific using an example?

Comment: Try replacing this in your code wiht the changes I made  PricebookEntry standardPrice = new PricebookEntry( Product2Id = prd1.Id, UnitPrice = 1, IsActive = true, UseStandardPrice = false);
        insert standardPrice;

Comment: Hi Suri, I did that and getting this error : System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Pricebook2Id]: [Pricebook2Id]

Comment: Check to see if a task can be linked to an order; if not then your "whatid=o.id" is the problem.

Comment: @RichardDurrant from what I know WhatId is for nonhuman objects therefore it can be used for orders

Comment: @TommyGeorgiou: Which insert is giving the error. If not the task then the PBE perhaps?

Comment: @RichardDurrant Yes it's the PBE that returns the error. But how to overcome this when I need the PBE for the OrderItem??

Comment: @TommyGeorgiou Remove UseStandardPrice = true and see if that helps. Doesn't make sense to add it when your PB is for the standaard one anyway. I have examples that work and I don't set this.

Comment: @RichardDurrant I have tried this before and I get the following error UnitPrice (unit price cannot be null): [UnitPrice]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working version of your code in my org...

```
        @istest
public static  void TaskTrigger_Test1()
{
        Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test');
        insert a;     

        Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();                         

        Product2 prd1 = new Product2 (Name='Test Product Entry 1',Description='Test Product Entry 1', isActive = true);
        insert prd1;

        PricebookEntry pe=new PricebookEntry(UnitPrice = 1,Product2Id=prd1.id,Pricebook2Id=pricebookId,isActive=true);
        insert pe;

        Order o = new Order(name='Test1',AccountId=a.id,EffectiveDate=system.today(),status='draft', PriceBook2Id=pricebookId);
        insert o;

        OrderItem oi = new OrderItem(OrderId=o.id,Quantity=1,PricebookEntryId=pe.id, unitPrice=1);
        insert oi;


    Task t = new Task(whatid=o.id,Priority = 'normal',status='open',subject='Email:xxxx');
    insert t;

    system.assertequals('Sent',o.status);
}
```

Differences are:- 1. Removed useStandardPrice from PBE. 2. Used your pricebookid variable. 3. Set the pricebookid from the order. 4. Set the UNIT PRICE for the order line item.

Comment: Still getting the null value for Unit Price

Comment: Getting there. Now it's failing because : System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: Sent, Actual: draft

Answer (score 3):

You should use `Test.getStandardPricebookId` ([documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_test.htm)) to make your life easier:

```
static testmethod void TaskTrigger_Test1()
{
    Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

    Product2 prd1; // = new Product2(...);
    insert prd1;

    PricebookEntry standardPrice = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id=pricebookId);
    PricebookEntry pe=new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id=pricebookId);
    //plus additional fields
    insert new List<PricebookEntry> { standardPrice, pe };
}
```

Comment: Hi Adrian thank you for your response. I have tried your solution but getting: Error: Compile Error: expecting a right angle bracket, found '{' at line 13 column 35

Comment: Didn't close my list declaration. Fixed.