# Product2id is not writeable Any work around for that

Tags: apex, opportunity-lineitem, product

I am trying to clone an opportunityLineItem but I am getting an error :

> Field is not writeable: OpportunityLineItem.Product2Id

```
public class OppLineItem {
public OpportunityLineItem objOpportunityLineItem{get;set;}
Pricebook2 pb = [Select id from Pricebook2 where isStandard = true limit 1];
public OppLineItem(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    objOpportunityLineItem = [SELECT Id,Opportunityid,
    ServiceDate,Product2id,TotalPrice,ListPrice,Asset__c,UnitPrice,Quantity,Description,Product2.Name FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE ID =:controller.getId() limit 1];
}

public PageReference onSave(){
    PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry();
    pbe.Pricebook2Id= pb.id;
    pbe.Product2Id = objOpportunityLineItem.Product2id;
    pbe.UnitPrice = 1000;
    insert pbe;
    OpportunityLineItem oliClone = new OpportunityLineItem ();
    oliClone.Opportunityid = objOpportunityLineItem.Opportunityid;
    oliClone.ServiceDate = objOpportunityLineItem.ServiceDate;
    //oliClone.Product2id = objOpportunityLineItem.Product2id;
    oliClone.TotalPrice = objOpportunityLineItem.TotalPrice;
    //oliClone.ListPrice = objOpportunityLineItem.ListPrice;
    oliClone.Asset__c = objOpportunityLineItem.Asset__c;
    oliClone.UnitPrice = objOpportunityLineItem.UnitPrice;
    oliClone.Quantity = objOpportunityLineItem.Quantity;
    oliClone.Description = objOpportunityLineItem.Description; 
    insert oliClone; 
    Pagereference pr = new PageReference('/'+oliClone.Id+'?retUrl=/'+oliClone.Id);
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    return pr;
}

}
```

Comment: roduct2Id is a read-only field available in API version 30.0 and later for OpportunityLineItem.  Use the PricebookEntryId field instead, specifying the ID of the PricebookEntry record.
Check this : https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm

Comment: @Ratan - why a comment? This looks like an answer to me :-)

Comment: yes, Ratan's comment is the answer. Always insert OLI's with PricebookentryId

Comment: @Guy ahh was about to add anwer for became busy with other stuffs.. thanks Added as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Product2Id is a read-only field available in API version 30.0 and later for OpportunityLineItem. Use the PricebookEntryId field instead, specifying the ID of the PricebookEntry record.

Check this : https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm

Comment: can you tell me how exactly I can do it... I am not getting how to use PricebookEntryId field...because I have made an object of PricebookEntry and its giving me an error.I am have edited my code.
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, This price definition already exists in this price book: []

Comment: @Anzar check this thread http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/68641/18731

Comment: in test class we can use  Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId(); but what about controller

Comment: not pricebookId but pricebookEntryId. Copy it from objOpportunityLineItem

Answer (score 2):

You can use the sObject clone() method ([link to sobject documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm)).

```
OpportunityLineItem oliClone = objOpportunityLineItem.clone(false, true, false, false);
```

The clone method will copy all of the fields that you have set or queried on `objOpportunityLineItem` (in other words, all of the fields on the object instance in memory), so that one line takes care of most of your `onSave()` method.

I prefer to make a deep clone, which is why the second argument to clone() in my example is set to true. Doing this means that you can alter the values of your cloned record's relationship fields without affecting the values of the relationship fields of the original record.

Having the deep clone is important if you're going to re-parent the cloned OpportunityLineItem and also update the original OpportunityLineItem.

Comment: same error is coming.

Comment: @Anzar It worked for me after adding `PricebookEntryId` to the list of fields queried for the `OpportunityLineItem` being cloned (Line 5 of your provided code).

Comment: an error is coming 
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: unknown (only one of unit price or total price may be specified): [unknown]

Comment: @Anzar that error is self-explanatory, and you should be able to work out what needs to be done. One solution would be to remove one of those two fields from your initial query.